# Python Mayavi2 @mayavi2.standalone

Tags: python, mayavi

I am starting to learn the Mayavi2 for 3D visualization with Python. 
In one of the [examples](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_unstructured_grid.html) from the [Mayavi 4.3.1 documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), the following command popped up:

```
@mayavi2.standalone
```

I thought the `@` character was not valid in a Python identifier.. anyway it seems the command does not work without the following import:

```
from mayavi.scripts import mayavi2
```

what does this command do? I tried to google for a documentation, but could not find any.

Comment: i think @ means that decorator. it clearly an decrator for the method view

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Thanks, I did not know about Python decorators.. Seems to be a useful concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given

```
@mayavi2.standalone
def view():
    from mayavi.sources.vtk_data_source import VTKDataSource
    from mayavi.modules.outline import Outline
    from mayavi.modules.surface import Surface
    from mayavi.modules.vectors import Vectors

    mayavi.new_scene()
    # The single type one
    src = VTKDataSource(data = ug1)
    mayavi.add_source(src)
    mayavi.add_module(Outline())
```

@mayavi2.standalone is decorator and it is valid python identifier.to know about [decorators](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

you can see the method standalone in mayavi2 module